# MySQL Join with condition of previous join

Tags: mysql

```
Select t3.* from table1 t1 
left join table2 t2  on t1.id_traslado=t2.id_traslado
inner join table3 t3 on IFNULL(t2.id_traslado,t3.id_traslado=t1.id_traslado,t3.id_pasajero=t2.id_pasajero)
```

I have a query similar to this, but obviously it's not woking, is there any way to join the third table with differents columns, depending if the second table contains any results?

**EDIT:**

The columns of the tables are like that:

t3===> id_reserva  id_prestacion  id_traslado(NULL)  id_pasajero(NULL)

t2(NULL) ===>id_traslado  id_pasajero

t1===>id_traslado

if t2 is not null, the relation between t3 and t1 with id_traslado doen't exits and it's replaced with t2 and t3 relation with id_pasajero

Comment: is there any relation between t1 and t3?

Comment: Yes, t2 relations with t3 with columnaux2 ... and t1 relations with t3 columnaux1

Answer (score 0):

use this way of join hope no need to check tabl2 data exist or not

```
Select * from table1 t1 
inner join table3 t3  on t1.columnaux1=t3.columnaux1
left join  table2 t2 on t3.columnaux2=t2.columnaux2
```

Comment: No.. i already think of that... the problem is that if the relation with table2 and table1 exists "inner join table3 t3  on t1.columnaux1=t3.columnaux1" this is null..

Comment: can you please share your sample data of 3 table and sample output it would help to give answer

Comment: i have updated the question, any ideas now?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
inner join table3 t3 on t3.columnaux1= COALESCE(t2.columnaux2, t1.columnaux1)
```